# What would an relativistically expanding sphere look like for an external observer?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity

Consider a reflecting sphere, whose radius is increasing at constant rate V close to light speed. What would the collision look like for a remote observer stationary relative to the centre of the sphere if a light source with spectrum of Sun is placed behind him? What would it look like if the observer is moving away with speed V? What would it like for a remote stationary observer, if V is not constant, but, say V(t)=C/t?

Comment: It would look like homework.

Comment: It's not homework (well, cannot prove that, but it really isn't).

Comment: Why don't you tell us a couple of your thoughts about the problem? That way you would come a lot closer to satisfying the minimal criteria of the site for "homework like problems and how to get help with them".

Comment: Your questions seems to boil down to what your reflection looks like in a mirror if it's moving at relativistic speed. Is that a fair comment? If so, I'm sure I've seen questions like that on this site, or if not a Google should quickly find some relevant articles.

Comment: John Rennie, thank you for the cue. Problem is, I have googled many interesting things about a mirror moving "in plane", parallel to the observer, but none about a mirror getting closer.

Comment: Is this just a Doppler-effect problem (i.e., white light being red-shifted due to the retreating reflecting surface)?

Comment: If I knew it is, I wouldn't ask.